# Kotlin Deserialize Any Type Not Supported

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON into a kotlin class using kotlin.serialization. However when the code goes to deserialize the json it throws the error `kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Any type is not supported`

Can anyone help me resolves this?

Product:

```
@Serializable
data class Product(
        val id: Int = 0,
        val name: String = "",
        val slug: String = "",
        val permalink: String = "",
        @SerialName("date_created") val dateCreated: String = "",
        @SerialName("date_created_gmt") val dateCreatedGmt: String = "",
        @SerialName("date_modified") val dateModified: String = "",
        @SerialName("date_modified_gmt") val dateModifiedGmt: String = "",
        val type: String = "",
        val status: String = "",
        val featured: Boolean = false,
        @SerialName("catalog_visibility") val catalogVisibility: String = "",
        val description: String = "",
        @SerialName("short_description") val shortDescription: String = "",
        val sku: String = "",
        val price: String = "",
        @SerialName("regular_price") val regularPrice: String = "",
        @SerialName("sale_price") val salePrice: String = "",
        @SerialName("on_sale") val onSale: Boolean = false,
        val purchasable: Boolean = false,
        @SerialName("total_sales") val totalSales: Int = 0,
        @SerialName("external_url") val externalUrl: String = "",
        @SerialName("tax_status") val taxStatus: String = "",
        @SerialName("tax_class") val taxClass: String = "",
        @SerialName("stock_quantity") val stockQuantity: String = "",
        @SerialName("stock_status") val stockStatus: String = "",
        val backorders: String = "",
        @SerialName("backorders_allowed") val backordersAllowed: Boolean = false,
        val backordered: Boolean = false,
        @SerialName("sold_individually") val soldIndividually: Boolean = false,
        val weight: String = "",
        val dimensions: ProductDimensions = ProductDimensions(),
        @SerialName("shipping_required") val shippingRequired: Boolean = false,
        @SerialName("shipping_taxable") val shippingTaxable: Boolean = false,
        @SerialName("shipping_class") val shippingClass: String = "",
        @SerialName("shipping_class_id") val shippingClassId: Int = 0,
        @SerialName("reviews_allowed") val reviewsAllowed: Boolean = false,
        @SerialName("average_rating") val averageRating: String = "",
        @SerialName("rating_count") val ratingCount: Int = 0,
        @SerialName("related_ids") val relatedIds: List<Int> = listOf(),
        @SerialName("upsell_ids") val upsellIds: List<Int> = listOf(),
        @SerialName("cross_sell_ids") val crossSellIds: List<Int> = listOf(),
        @SerialName("parent_id") val parentId: Int = 0,
        @SerialName("purchase_note") val purchaseNote: String = "",
        val categories: List<ProductCategory> = listOf(),
        val images: List<ProductImage> = listOf(),
        val attributes: List<ProductAttribute> = listOf(),
        val variations: List<Int> = listOf()
)
```

ProductDimension:

```
data class ProductDimensions(
        val length: String = "",
        val width: String = "",
        val height: String = ""
)
```

Product Attribute:

```
data class ProductAttribute(
        val id: Int = 0,
        val name: String = "",
        val position: Int = 0,
        val visible: Boolean = false,
        val variation: Boolean = false,
        val options: List<String> = listOf()
)
```

Product Category:

```
data class ProductCategory(
        val id: Int = 0,
        val name: String = "",
        val slug: String = ""
)
```

Product Image:

```
data class ProductImage(
        val id: Int = 0,
        @SerialName("date_created") val dateCreated: String = "",
        @SerialName("date_created_gmt") val dateCreatedGmt: String = "",
        @SerialName("date_modified") val dateModified: String = "",
        @SerialName("date_modified_gmt") val dateModifiedGmt: String = "",
        val src: String = "",
        val name: String = "",
        val alt: String = ""
)
```

And the associated json is on pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/cqJQaa88)

Comment: Can you add the data class for: ProductDimensions, ProductCategory, ProductImage, and ProductAttribute

Comment: @Gomino added the code

Comment: Can you tell me which version of kotlin and kotlin.serialization you're using?

Comment: @Gomino 1.3 now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working [cloud9](https://ide.c9.io/gomino/kotlin_serialization) (simply run `./gradlew run`) solution using the last version of Kotlin (1.3.0) and the serialization runtime (0.9.0)

```
val serializer = Product.serializer().list
val json = JSON.nonstrict.parse<List<Product>>(serializer, jsonString)
```

Note that some attributes had to have the @Optional annotation added for this serialization to work with your sample, hence the nonstrict version of the parsing.

```
@Serializable
data class Product(
        val id: Int = 0,
        val name: String = "",
        val slug: String = "",
        val permalink: String = "",
        @Optional @SerialName("date_created") val dateCreated: String = "",
        @SerialName("date_created_gmt") val dateCreatedGmt: String = "",
        @SerialName("date_modified") val dateModified: String = "",
        @SerialName("date_modified_gmt") val dateModifiedGmt: String = "",
        val type: String = "",
        val status: String = "",
        val featured: Boolean = false,
        @SerialName("catalog_visibility") val catalogVisibility: String = "",
        val description: String = "",
        @SerialName("short_description") val shortDescription: String = "",
        val sku: String = "",
        val price: String = "",
        @SerialName("regular_price") val regularPrice: String = "",
        @SerialName("sale_price") val salePrice: String = "",
        @SerialName("on_sale") val onSale: Boolean = false,
        val purchasable: Boolean = false,
        @SerialName("total_sales") val totalSales: Int = 0,
        @SerialName("external_url") val externalUrl: String = "",
        @SerialName("tax_status") val taxStatus: String = "",
        @SerialName("tax_class") val taxClass: String = "",
        @SerialName("stock_quantity") val stockQuantity: String = "",
        @Optional @SerialName("stock_status") val stockStatus: String = "",
        val backorders: String = "",
        @SerialName("backorders_allowed") val backordersAllowed: Boolean = false,
        val backordered: Boolean = false,
        @SerialName("sold_individually") val soldIndividually: Boolean = false,
        val weight: String = "",
        val dimensions: ProductDimensions = ProductDimensions(),
        @SerialName("shipping_required") val shippingRequired: Boolean = false,
        @SerialName("shipping_taxable") val shippingTaxable: Boolean = false,
        @SerialName("shipping_class") val shippingClass: String = "",
        @SerialName("shipping_class_id") val shippingClassId: Int = 0,
        @SerialName("reviews_allowed") val reviewsAllowed: Boolean = false,
        @SerialName("average_rating") val averageRating: String = "",
        @SerialName("rating_count") val ratingCount: Int = 0,
        @SerialName("related_ids") val relatedIds: List<Int> = listOf(),
        @SerialName("upsell_ids") val upsellIds: List<Int> = listOf(),
        @SerialName("cross_sell_ids") val crossSellIds: List<Int> = listOf(),
        @SerialName("parent_id") val parentId: Int = 0,
        @SerialName("purchase_note") val purchaseNote: String = "",

        val categories: List<ProductCategory> = listOf(),
        val images: List<ProductImage> = listOf(),
        val attributes: List<ProductAttribute> = listOf(),
        val variations: List<Int> = listOf()
)
```

Notice: `date_created`, `stock_status`

A good online tool to generate your data class based on your json raw data is [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io?share=oUqUYQTvQ4NZMujLZ9VC)

Edit: Just figured out that cloud9 had been acquired by amazon two years ago, and you can no longer create an account to see public workspace.
So here is the [link to the filesystem](https://preview.c9users.io/gomino/kotlin_serialization/)

Comment: How to do for MutableMap<String, String>?

Comment: Thanks for the tool's link.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried this and couldn't replicate your problem.  Can you maybe provide a github repo where we can see the problem?

There was one issue in the JSON in your pastebin link, which was that the `stock_status` value was missing, so I hit this error: `kotlinx.serialization.MissingFieldException: Field stock_status is required, but it was missing`

However once I added that value into the JSON I could deserialize it fine.

Here's the code I used:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JSON
import java.io.File

val product = JSON(strictMode = false).parseList<Product>(File("./serializationTest.json").readText())
```

The other thing is that according to the [documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization)

> Using Kotlin Serialization requires Kotlin compiler 1.3.0 or higher.

Kotlin 1.3 was only officially released very recently, so are you maybe using a release candidate or something, instead of the formal release (with which it worked for me)?  Maybe update all your dependencies to the latest versions and try again?

Comment: Your code throws an error "this declaration is experimental and must be marked with '@kotlinx.serialization.ImplicitReflectionSerializer'"

Comment: Try this instead: `val products = JSON(strictMode = false).parse(Product.serializer().list, File("./serializationTest.json").readText())`